# C# Task.ContinueWith() vs java?

Tags: java, c#, guava, completable-future

in C# , [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) class has `ContinueWith` method, when the task runs to complete status, the `ContinueWith` method will be invoked, and in JAVA, is there some methods like `ContinueWith` ?

I know the guava `listenablefuture`, but it use a new thread to wait the 'task' to complete, is it equal to C#  `ContinueWith`?

and JAVA 8 [`CompletableFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) `whenComplete` has the same effect, so what's the difference in C#  `ContinueWith` `listenablefuture` `CompletableFuture`?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A `Task` in .Net and a `CompletableFuture` in Java accomplish a very similar purpose.  They provide a reference to something that is executing in a different thread (a `TaskScheduler` in .Net or an `Executor` in Java), with the ability to wait for the result and/or perform different actions on completion.

There are a couple of differences between `Task.ContinueWith` and `CompletableFuture.whenComplete`.  For one, the function passed into the .Net version takes the `Task` itself as an argument, requiring an additional step to get its result (or to propagate downstream exceptions if necessary).  The function passed into Java version takes the result of the task as an argument.

The other significant difference is the thread on which the continuation task will run.  In .Net, it will by default run on a different thread from the main task.  In Java, it will by default run on the same thread as the main task.  These default actions can be overridden in both cases.